# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() with g_string_free()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glib, libmysql

I have a `GList` which contains a collection of `GSList`. This GSlist contains a collection of `GString`.  When I free the whole `GList`, I get segmentation fault.

Now check the following code.

```
GList *m_rows = NULL;
m_rows = mysql_multiple_rows(mysql, sql1->str);

g_list_foreach(m_rows, mysql_storage_load_settings, &data);
mysql_free_multiple_rows(m_rows); /// <----------------------- works just fine

m_rows = mysql_multiple_rows(mysql, sql2->str);

if(g_list_length(m_rows)>0){
    g_list_foreach(m_rows, mysql_storage_load_accounts, &data);
    mysql_free_multiple_rows(m_rows); /// <----------------------- Segmentation fault!
}else{
    fprintf(stderr, "\e[31m\tUser has no account!\e[0m");
}
```

So `m_rows` are only allocated using `g_string_new()`,  `g_slist_prepend()` and `g_list_prepend()`. `g_string_new()` creates new `GString` and added to a `GSList`. all the resultant `GSList` then get added to `GList`. It happens in `mysql_multiple_rows` function.

They are `free`'d using `mysql_free_multiple_rows`. This function just does the reverse.

See the clean up functions.

```
static void mysql_free_multiple_rows(GList *table){
    g_list_free_full(table, mysql_free_single_row);
}
static void mysql_free_single_row(gpointer data){
    g_slist_free_full(data, msyql_free_single_row_field); // data here is GSlist
}
static void msyql_free_single_row_field(gpointer data){
    g_string_free(data, TRUE); // data here is GString actually
}
```

Could anyone tell me why I am getting this error? As both the memory allocation and de-allocation sequence are same I have no clue why its happening.

1. [**Valgrind output**](http://pastie.org/4278628)
2. [**Source file**](https://gist.github.com/3137199)

Comment: I think we need to see more code, at least some of `mysql_storage_load_accounts()`. Does it have some error conditions?

Comment: @MichałGórny I have updated the question. See the last link

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you seem to be freeing `password` in `mysql_storage_load_accounts()`. I don't see any special handling for it, so my first guess would be that it gets freed twice.

Comment: omg! that was it. I failed to see that line. could you post it as an answer @MichałGórny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, you seem to be freeing `password` in `mysql_storage_load_accounts()`. However, I don't see any special handling for it, so my guess would be that it gets freed twice.